# R read a csv file without carriage return

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to read a .csv downloaded on Ishares' website containing all holdings of an ETF (and additional info).

[Here is the csv](https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239741/ishares-global-energy-etf/1467271812596.ajax?fileType=csv&fileName=IXC_holdings&dataType=fund).

My issue is that I can't get a neat dataframe containing Tickers, company name, asset class, etc. using the `read.csv` function.

When I opened the csv file in notepad I saw that all rows are on the same line and no special character is used to separate rows from each others.

Do you have any clues on how should I deal with this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That csv file uses the "LF" line break convention found on Linux and other Unixes - Windows usually expects text files to use the "CRLF" convention, which is why the line breaks are not showing in notepad.  Another issue with that file is that before the csv content there are 10 header lines.  Does this work in R?

```
read.csv(<fname>, skip=10)
```

If the line breaks are still an issue, there must be a Windows tool to convert from LF linebreaks to CRLF. On Linux it's "unix2dos" - I'm not sure what it would be on Windows.

Comment: Yes it does Sir! Thank you so much!